# Tabla Dinamica con AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, tabla-dinámica

necesito poder cargar una tabla con productos.

El sistema funciona de la siguiente manera: Tengo un select en el cual figuran todos los productos (mas de 100) y cuando le hago click a uno lo debe cargar automáticamente en una tabla que se encuentra abajo (una especie de carrito) para que al finalizar la selección de productos yo aprete en "Generar Pedido" y pueda enviar eso.

Me podrían dar una mano de como hacer algo así? Pense en tener un $scope.pedido e ir llenándolo con otros $scope.producto pero no se bien como hacer algo del estilo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A continuación puedo darte una guía de como puedes resolver tu problema y puede que el siguiente código te ayude a mejorar tus resultado, lo que tu necesitas es tener una variable definida algo como: **$scope.itemArray = []**, donde puedas almacenar los `items` que vallas agregando al carrito con la funcion `push()`, puedes ver el código, para que te hagas una idea, quedo atento.

**PD: Este código es totalmente AngularJs**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {


    $scope.alert = false;
    $scope.itemsToCar = [];
    $scope.items = {
        "productos": [ 
            {
                "cantidad": "2",
                "idProducto": 1,
                "descripcion": "Papel de cocina",
                "precio": 300000
            },
            {
                "cantidad": "5",
                "idProducto": 2,
                "descripcion": "Juguetes de bebe",
                "precio": 20000
            },
            {
                "cantidad": "23",
                "idProducto": 3,
                "descripcion": "Pelotas",
                "precio": 466000
            },
            {
                "cantidad": "7",
                "idProducto": 4,
                "descripcion" : "Ropa de hombre",
                "precio": 15620
            }
        ],
        
        "carros": [ 
            {
                "cantidad": "42",
                "idProducto": 1,
                "descripcion": "Carros Kia",
                "precio": 3000000
            },
            {
                "cantidad": "56",
                "idProducto": 2,
                "descripcion": "Carros Mazda",
                "precio": 2000000
            },
            {
                "cantidad": "105",
                "idProducto": 3,
                "descripcion": "Carros TOYOTA",
                "precio": 4660000
            },
            {
                "cantidad": "7",
                "idProducto": 4,
                "descripcion" : "Camionetas",
                "precio": 1562000
            }
        ]        
    }

    $scope.mostrarInformacion = function(description) {
        $scope.showInfoTable = description;
        $scope.alert = false;
    }

    $scope.alerta = function(item) {
        $scope.item = item;
        $scope.alert = true;
        $scope.itemsToCar.push(item);
    }       
    
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div class="container">
        <select 
            class="custom-select" 
            name="itemDescripcion" 
            ng-model="itemSelected" 
            ng-change="mostrarInformacion(itemSelected)" 
            style="margin: 20px 0px;">

            <option value="" disabled selected>Tipo de item</option>
            <option ng-value="y" ng-repeat="(categoria, y) in items">{{ categoria }}</option>

        </select>
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Cantidad</th>
                    <th scope="col">idProducto</th>
                    <th scope="col">Descripcion</th>
                    <th scope="col">Precio</th>
                    <th scope="col">Agregar al carrito</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="item in showInfoTable">
                <td scope="row" ng-bind="item.cantidad"></td>
                <td ng-bind="item.idProducto"></td>
                <td ng-bind="item.descripcion"></td>
                <td ng-bind="item.precio | currency"></td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="alerta(item)">Add</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert" ng-if="alert">
          Se ha agregado el item <strong>{{ item.descripcion }}</strong> al carrito
        </div>
        <h2>Item en el carrito: {{ itemsToCar.length }}</h2>
        <pre>
            {{ itemsToCar | json }}
        </pre>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Genial! Es exactamente eso, muchas gracias!! Ahora estoy tratando de eliminar algún elemento del carrito :)!

Comment: @JuanManuel245 y ya sabes como hacerlo? te puedo ayudar.

Comment: Ya lo pude resolver! Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Me autorespondo:

1) Creo e inicializo la variable: `var carrito = [];`

2) Le hago un push con los datos que vienen por variable, en este caso producto

```
productoCarrito.push({
      'cant' : 1,
      'prod' : producto.id,
      'desc' : producto.descripcion,
      'precio' : 0

    });
```

Comment: Esta solución te ha servidor para tu pregunta?

Comment: Si! pero no se como cerrar el post!